# How to fix Python If Statement for finding Taxicab numbers?

Tags: python

I am working on a script that finds Taxicab numbers (numbers such that n is the sum of two cubes in at least two different ways) less than or equal to a specific value.

In my script t is my current variable that tries to the max taxicab number that can be printed but the script print one value beyond the limit I set.

```
t = 10000
cubes, crev = [x**3 for x in range(1,1000)], {}
# for cube root lookup
for x,x3 in enumerate(cubes): crev[x3] = x + 1

sums = sorted(x + y for x in cubes for y in cubes if y < x)

idx = 0
n = 0
for i in range(1, len(sums)-1):
    if sums[i-1] != sums[i] and sums[i] == sums[i+1]:
        if n<t:
            idx += 1
            n = sums[i]
            print "%10d"%(n)
        else:
            break
```

with output:

```
1729
4104
13832
```

And having set t = 10000 expected and desired output is:

```
1729
4104
```

Does anyone know how to get the if statement to behave as desired? I spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to make this one small change..

Comment: well, you change n after you perform the test.  Consider putting the if n < t test just before the print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BlivetWidget pointed out, you're checking the *old* value of `n`, but printing the *new* value of `n`. Try changing your code like this.

Old:

```
if sums[i-1] != sums[i] and sums[i] == sums[i+1]:
    if n<t:
        idx += 1
        n = sums[i]
        print "%10d"%(n)
    else:
        break
```

New:

```
if sums[i-1] != sums[i] and sums[i] == sums[i+1]:
    idx += 1
    n = sums[i]
    if n<t:
        print "%10d"%(n)
    else:
        break
```

That will be a good start. Then you can make a few more changes, like get rid of the `idx` value you aren't using. And you don't really need `n` either, since it's just another way of writing `sums[i]`:

```
if sums[i-1] != sums[i] and sums[i] == sums[i+1]:
    if sums[i]<t:
        print "%10d"%(sums[i])
    else:
        break
```

That looks a lot simpler, and should do what you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you!! For both the advice on how to make the changes needed and on simplifying the code.

Answer (score 0):

n = sums[i] should be taken out of the if condition.

```
for i in range(1, len(sums)-1):
    if sums[i-1] != sums[i] and sums[i] == sums[i+1]:
        n = sums[i]
        if n<t:
            idx += 1
            print(n)
        else:
            break
```